# DAO Design with Child Objects

Tags: object-oriented-design, dao

If I have objects that represent a hierarchy of relationships.  For example:

Person
  Spouse
    Spouse Contact
    Spouse Address
  Person Contact
  Person Address

Each of the items listed has a database table related to an object.  Each object/table has an ID, Parent ID (Spouse ID for Spouse Address records) and Base ID (Person in the example).  Given that hierarchies can be arbitrarily deep and wide, how would you design the objects and data access layer?

Comment: isn't spouse a person too?

Comment: yay its a contrived example from something I was staring at, its more of just the hierarchal relationship.

Comment: @Mithir Not always. Some are beasts too

Comment: Why not have a RelatedPeople table and a Relationships table? So the RelatedPeople table would match up two people and say what the relationship is.